# Event to handle the deletion of attachments while composing a New Mail

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, outlook-addin

Hi I am new to outlook addin programming.
I have a doubt and can not find anything related to this.

I want to capture the event in C# as and when an end user deletes a selected attachment from a compose mail by any means like by pressing backspace in attachment section.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the MailItem.AttachmentDelete event.

Comment: Thanks for replying Dmitry. But I can not find this method anywhere.

Comment: It is not a method - it is an event. What is your current code?